Azure DevOps: multiple agents on the same self-hosted vm?
Has someone tried installing multiple agents on the same self-hosted VM? Anyone able to share his experience traveling in this scenario? Any drawbacks or side-effects?

In my last company they had 3 or 4 VMs, each one with multiple build agents. There's nothing wrong in doing it, but if you can run the build agents in Docker containers instead of installing the agents directly into a VM - it will save you a lot of headaches :-)

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455645/is-it-advantageous-to-have-multiple-build-agents-on-the-same-machine, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56254697/running-multiple-build-agents-and-deployment-agents-that-service-different-organ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40797253/vsts-build-agents-can-one-computer-run-multiple-build-agents

It is not recommended to install multiple agents on the same machine. This might adversely affect performance and the result of your pipelines. See the statement on this docs.
